# Basic cdb: does cdb vary how it notates scope?

Tags: c, cdb

If I compile:

```
int *a;

void main(void)
{
    *a = 1;
}
```

and then disassemble main in cdb I get:

```
pointersproject!main:
00000001`3fd51010 mov     rax,qword ptr [pointersproject!a (00000001`3fd632f0)]
00000001`3fd51017 mov     dword ptr [rax],1
00000001`3fd5101d xor     eax,eax
00000001`3fd5101f ret
```

So *a is symbolized by pointersproject!a. All good.

However, if I declare the pointer within main:

```
void main(void)
{
    int *a;
    a = 1;
}
```

I see that a is just an offset from the stack pointer (I believe), rather then the human-readable structure I'd expect (like, say pointersproject!main!a):

```
pointersproject!main:
00000001`3fd51010 sub     rsp,18h
00000001`3fd51014 mov     rax,qword ptr [rsp]
00000001`3fd51018 mov     dword ptr [rax],1
00000001`3fd5101e xor     eax,eax
00000001`3fd51020 add     rsp,18h
00000001`3fd51024 ret
```

This is probably as much about my understanding of what the compiler's done as anything else but: can anyone explain why the notation for a isn't what I expect?

(This inspired by musing while looking at x64 Windows Debugging: Practical Foundations by Dmitry Vostokov).

Comment: As an aside - you can get `cdb` to display the local variables for a stack frame using the `dv` command.  Look at the `debugger.chm` file for details on the various options. For example, `dv /t /v` will show the address, type and value of the local variables. You can determine what the current stack frame context is (if you want it to be something else) using the `.frame` command. Reading `debugger.chm` is time well spent. In addition to the full information about the commands for the incredibly powerful debuggers, there's useful info about Windows and assembly language, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a variable is defined inside a function, it is an automatic variable unless explicitly declared static. Such variables only live during the execution of the function and are normally allocated in the stack, thus they are deallocated when the function exits. The change you see in the complied code is not due to the change in scope but to the change from static to automatic variable. If you make a static, it will not be allocated in the stack, even if its scope is the function main.

Comment: That feels like a slightly oblique answer. Is it not because the assembly redirects the rsp to the location of a in the stack, and then manipulates the contents of memory at the location pointed to by rsp? Because the address of a is never used directly, the notation can't be used?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your comment, but the point is that a has to be allocated anew each time the function is called. If main were called recursively, another variable a would have to be allocated. Thus the current instance of a lives in a certain place relative to the stack. This could mean different addresses when a function is called from different places.

Comment: I understand what you mean :) Your edit -- "The change you see ..." clears it up a bit. However -- none of my variables are static at the moment. In the first case, a has program scope. So, the notation represents variables at program scope, and not at local scope?

Comment: Also, if I declare the local var static in the second example then the notation reappears. I don't quite understand that; even though the lifetime has changed, the scope hasn't.

Comment: In the first case, the variable has global scope **and** is static, meaning it is allocated before execution and lives until program termination. Local variables are automatic unless declared static. Confusingly, the same keyword (static) is used to indicate that variables declared outside a function body (which are static anyway) should be invisible outside the current module (i.e. it is used as a scope declaration!). Keep in mind that scope does not determine whether the variable goes to the stack or to the data segment; its static/automatic character does.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense -- my C's pretty rusty, which is what inspired this in the first place. Thanks for reminding me of the terminology!

Comment: And: http://www.cnblogs.com/WarrenTang/archive/2008/03/30/1129991.html for my own future reference

Comment: I don't blame you; I have sometimes wondered why these two quite different uses of `static`. Keywords must have been expensive once :)